# Get the topmost window's handle at position x/y

Tags: c#, winapi, window-handles

Say I have four windows displayed on the screen at once, each in their own corner and the top left is in focus with the mouse hovered over it. Is there a way to tell Windows to identify what window is at position X/Y on display at the top, let's say the bottom right for example, get it's handle and return it to me, all without moving the mouse?

Comment: [`WindowFromPoint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-windowfrompoint) will give you the window handle (`HWND`) of the window that exists as the specified point, in virtual screen coordinates. I *believe* that's what you want, although your description is somewhat unclear to me. If you want the window that has the focus, then [`GetActiveWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getactivewindow) will tell you its handle.

Comment: @CodyGray Yes, I think this is it, thanks.

Comment: This question gets somewhat more interesting with "non-rectangular" windows, implemented using `WM_NCHITTEST`.